# Determine Correct Solution Platform for NokiaImagingSDK

Tags: windows-phone-8, nokia-imaging-sdk, lumia-imaging-sdk

I have started playing around with the Nokia Imaging SDK, and I am wondering about what should be the correct Solution Platform when submitting an application to the Marketplace? Currently I have the following

[image]

Is this the correct setup to be able to successfully submit an application to the Marketplace for Certification?

Comment: I have submitted ARM version of my app which uses Nokia Imaging SDK and it passed certification and is available on the Store. Which makes sense really: X86 - emulator, ARM - devices.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make my comment the answer for others to see

You should use ARM Release build. ARM for devices, X86 only when testing on emulator.

I have submitted ARM version of my app which uses Nokia Imaging SDK and it passed certification and is available on the Store.

It's also been asked [on Nokia Developer forum.](http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/243439-Which-Xap-file-is-to-be-submitted-to-windows-phone-store)